# Kerkis font activation error in latex

Tags: pdftex, latex3, preamble

I am trying use kerkis font in latex using `\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}`.

The following is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{scrextend}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small}
\usepackage{setspace}

\graphicspath{{img/Ch1/}}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{nocaption}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{ colorlinks, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}




\begin{document}


Some texts here.
A math equation example
 \begin{align}
    \Omega &= [\nabla \times {\cal A}]_z \nonumber\\
    &= \frac{\partial {\cal A}_y}{\partial k_x} - \frac{\partial {\cal A}_x}{\partial k_y}
\end{align} 


\end{document}
```

However I am getting an error:
"Command \iint already defined. ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}"

Can anyone suggest me what went wrong in the preamble?

Comment: Move    `\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}`     after    `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: Still getting another error: "This package is obsolete. Disabling it and(filecontents) passing control to the filecontents environment(filecontents) defined by the LaTeX kernel."

Comment: @HopeFul Try my minimal complete code.

Comment: @HopeFul the `filecontents` one is a warning, not an error; you can just remove `filecontents` (it's now in the kernel).

Comment: @Hope Ful Works perfectly for me, your distribution may need some updates! See what Sebastiano suggest you!

Comment: I updated the miktex and now all the suggestions are working.

Comment: Perfectly! Take care to be updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have restricted your MWE and it works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{graphicx}




\begin{document}


Some texts here.
A math equation example
 \begin{align}
    \Omega &= [\nabla \times {\cal A}]_z \nonumber\\
    &= \frac{\partial {\cal A}_y}{\partial k_x} - \frac{\partial {\cal A}_x}{\partial k_y}
\end{align} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still I am getting an error. "Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf."

Comment: @HopeFul It will be a technical problem of updating your LaTeX distribution.

Comment: Thank you. I updated and now it is compiling successfully generating a beautiful pdf. . However, getting another error: "pdflatex: major issue: User/administrator updates are out-of-sync."

Comment: @HopeFul you should probably ask a new question regarding that issue to be honest, this answer and the follow-up comment by Sebastiano have answered this question as-is, it helps keep the site clean if new questions/issues are asked as new questions so that it helps future people - someone else might run into your issue and appreciate an answer/question! If this answer answered your question, please consider ticking it as correct (the tick arrow next to the answer).

Comment: @JamesT Now I have marked this answer as correct. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @Sayan no worries, glad it helped and I upvoted your Q, feel free to link to this question (underneath your question/this answer is a button called `Share`), you can ask a new question and then share the link to this question as a follow-up. Just helps keep the site clean and helps other people in the future :)